# Best index for particular column often filtered with IS NULL?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I'm a bit unsure over the best index to use for a particular column in my table.

I have a [Deleted] column that is a DateTime, and represents the moment that the record was "deleted" from the system (it's a soft delete, so the physical record itself is not deleted).

Almost all queries hitting the table will have a 'WHERE [Deleted] IS NULL' filter to it.  I am not worried about the performance of queries that do no have this filter.

What would be the best index to construct for this scenario?  A filtered Index WHERE [Deleted] IS NULL?  An index on a computed column of definition IsDeleted = Deleted IS NOT NULL ?  I'm a bit unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have said `almost all the queries` will have this clause in them. I would suggest to add a `BIT` column to your table, once a row is deleted (Soft deletion) set it to 1. Also keep this Datetime column probably as Deleted_Datetime to keep track of when records are being deleted.

Then Create a Filtered Index on that BIT field something like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCIX_Deleted_Data
ON dbo.Table(Deleted)
WHERE Deleted = 0
```

Bit being the smallest datatype, and having a filtered index on it will give you a massive performance boost.

You can create this filtered index on your Datetime column as well. But the logic is in that case sql server will have to go through 8 bytes of data on index to see if row is filtered or not.

Whereas if you have Bit column sql server will have to go through 1 byte of data to filter it out or to keep it.

Smaller data quick processing, Bigger data more time to process it :).

Comment: BIT is actually stored as an INT (4 Bytes), it would create a smaller index if you'd use `CHAR(1)`.

Comment: From MSDN `"The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on."`

Comment: @Tomalak: no, BIT is stored as a bit. See [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx).

Comment: Ah. Maybe my knowledge is a bit off, I believe older SQL Server versions used INT unconditionally

Comment: You will need 32 Bit columns to reach 4 Bytes of data.

Comment: @RemusRusanu It is not. It says right on the page you link to.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lost battle. You can add a filter to all *other* indexes, see [filtered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx). But you won't be able to filter the clustered index.

A filter on `Deleted` column will be too unselective for NULLs and all queries would hit the [index tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/). And a `bit` Deleted column is worse, with a 0/1 selectivity it will be *always* ignored.

I would recommend you investigate [partitioned views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx) instead. You can store current data in one table, deleted data in another one, and operate over a view that unions the two. When properly designed (this is why reading the link is critical, to understand the 'proper' part) this scheme works fine and you never scan the 'cold' data.

Comment: Bit confused as to why you make reference to a clustered index.  My [Deleted] column isn't a clustered index, in this case.